# Is there an online chess game or app that allows for custom setup of pieces and printing this setup?

Tags: online-chess

I want to setup positions for my grandsons to show different tactics and print them. Lichess is excellent except that it won't print the pieces on the board. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a PC, Mac, iPhone, or Android? I have some suggestions, but I might tailor them based on what platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, the easiest way may just to set up the position you want on lichess.org, and use the Windows "Snipping Tool" to grab, and print, whatever part of the screen that you want.

This is not a tactic, but that is what I just did here:

[image]

Comment: yes, thank you, this works fine! John

Comment: @JohnCollins Still, if you send me a direct message at chess.com, if you already own certain materials, I may have a method that you do not even have to enter the games, and is A LOT easier. I have MANY databases of kids books that I use, or have created myself. If you have any of the ChessBase programs, or even if you install the FREE ChessBase reader, I would send you any for any books you already own (I am not into copyright infringement). That way, you would not have to enter any positions at all. Just open, and hit the print button.

Comment: Also, since this worked for you, if you would upvote (click the little up-arrow) and accept the answer (click the checkmark), I would appreciate it.

Comment: I also have some other things that I can send you that would be very helpful to teaching kids that are not protected.

Answer (score 1):

My diagram editor allows you to set up a position and save it as an image file, which can be printed separately: https://www.apronus.com/chess/diagram/editor/